# How to create variational autoencoder using python?

Tags: python

I want to create variational autoencoder, but shows me an error. In my opinion, a code is correct, but the code is not compiled. I will be grateful if someone shows me where is a problem. This is error:

> 2022-02-09 18:21:50.899323: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
> 2022-02-09 18:21:50.899461: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
> 2022-02-09 18:21:53.521726: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
> 2022-02-09 18:21:53.523385: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cublas64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublas64_11.dll not found
> 2022-02-09 18:21:53.524966: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cublasLt64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublasLt64_11.dll not found
> 2022-02-09 18:21:53.526537: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cufft64_10.dll'; dlerror: cufft64_10.dll not found
> 2022-02-09 18:21:53.528244: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'curand64_10.dll'; dlerror: curand64_10.dll not found
> 2022-02-09 18:21:53.529968: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cusolver64_11.dll'; dlerror: cusolver64_11.dll not found
> 2022-02-09 18:21:53.531734: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cusparse64_11.dll'; dlerror: cusparse64_11.dll not found
> 2022-02-09 18:21:53.533828: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudnn64_8.dll'; dlerror: cudnn64_8.dll not found
> 2022-02-09 18:21:53.534012: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1850] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
> Skipping registering GPU devices...
> 2022-02-09 18:21:53.534619: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:151] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
> To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\test.py", line 19, in 
> z = Lambda(sample, output_shape=(latent_dim,), name='z')([mu, log_var])
> File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
> raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
> File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\type_spec.py", line 890, in type_spec_from_value
> raise TypeError(f"Could not build a TypeSpec for {value} of "
> TypeError: Could not build a TypeSpec for KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 5), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='tf.**operators**.add/AddV2:0', description="created by layer 'tf.**operators**.add'") of unsupported type <class 'keras.engine.keras_tensor.KerasTensor'>.

```
    import keras.backend as K
    from keras.layers import Dense, Input, Lambda
    from keras.models import Model

    input_shape = (10,)
    intermediate_dim = 10
    latent_dim = 5

    inputs = Input(shape = input_shape, name = 'encoder_input')
    x = Dense(intermediate_dim, activation='relu')(inputs)
    mu = Dense(latent_dim, name='mu')(x)
    log_var = Dense(latent_dim, name='log_sigma')(x)

    def sample(a):
        mu, sigma = a
        epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=(1, latent_dim))
        return mu + K.exp(.5*log_var) * epsilon

    z = Lambda(sample, output_shape=(latent_dim,), name='z')([mu, log_var])

    encoder = Model(inputs, z, name='encoder')
    encoder.summary()
```

Comment: "Shows me an error"? *What error*?

Comment: I added errors to post

Comment: Looks like you didn't install something correctly, specifically for your GPU (assuming you have one, and it has CUDA)

Comment: I think the problem is Lambda, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59340096/18164055)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.